# AWS IoT button Deletion stuck on principals

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to delete an AWS IoT Button added to the AWS IoT Resources page at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iot/home?region=us-east-1#/dashboard

But when I check the button name and select Action Delete, I get error message 
"The action failed because the input is not valid. Cannot delete. Thing AWS-iot-button-01 is still attached to one or more principals".

I'm not able to delete any policy or certs. But I have been able to revoke them.

Comment: The IOT will not get deleted till you  detach things, certificates and policies revoking will not help.